# Dynamically loading and static loading modules in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, loading

Is any difference between the dynamically loading and static loading modules in Django?
How about its efficiency? Who can tell me the principles about the mechanism of dynamically loading and static loading modules in Django?

Answer (score 0):

First, this is a Python question, not a Django one as modules are a Python concept.

Secondly, there is no such thing as static loading in Python because it's an dynamic language by essence.

Therefor, loading a module in Python is always dynamic.

The only thing you should know are:

- once a module is imported, the code is executed;
- if you import the module again, Python get the reference from the first loading so it's fast and does not execute the code again;
- you can use `import` in a function, but it's not recommanded and the imported module won't be available outside of teh function scope.

The last options is the closest thing to 'dynamic loading', as you can choose what to import at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Due to python nature, all code is loaded (== executed) dynamically.

If you determine the module name only at runtime, you can use the [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) function:

```
s = "simplemodule" if use_simple else "extendedmodule"
mymodule = __import__(s)
mymodule.myfunction()
```

You can also [`reload()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) a previously loaded module (for example, if you have changed it's source code).